# how to create records of Permission Set Mappings

Tags: apex, rest-api

so whenever the Permission Set Mappings are create in external credential so i want to create one record for that automatically

so can anyone have idea on this i don't know this scenario is possible or not

can anyone help e to figure it out

Thnks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not plain SObject like account or contact, so you cannot create/insert it through apex or dataloader. Those are metadata so if you want to create them programmatically you need to use metadataAPI or some IDE extension to help you with it (like Salesforce extension for VS Code).

Check out this documentation about [ExternalCredentials](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_externalcredential.htm), especially the code snippet in the end.

```xml
<ExternalCredential xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>SampleExternalCredential</label>
    <authenticationProtocol>AwsSv4</authenticationProtocol>
    <externalCredentialParameters>
        <parameterName>Principal</parameterName>
        <parameterType>NamedPrincipal</parameterType>
        <principal>SamplePermissionSet</principal>
        <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
    </externalCredentialParameters>
    <externalCredentialParameters>
        <parameterName>AwsService</parameterName>
        <parameterValue>iam</parameterValue>
        <parameterType>AuthParameter</parameterType>
    </externalCredentialParameters>
    <externalCredentialParameters>
        <parameterName>AwsRegion</parameterName>
        <parameterValue>us-east-1</parameterValue>
        <parameterType>AuthParameter</parameterType>
    </externalCredentialParameters>
</ExternalCredential>
```

This is the metadata representation of the permission set mapping you are talking about.